# How do you remove \r and \n using re.py?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to remove \r's and \n's and "\ from a json url site but everytime I try it keeps getting cut off when I output the results. There are:

```
\r\n\r\n
\n\n
\n
\r
"\wordhere"\
```

If you can help me I would appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex for this.
You could use the `replace` method from string class.

```py
string = 'abc\r\n\r\n\\\\'
string = string.replace('\r', '')
string = string.replace('\n', '')
string = string.replace('\\', '')
```

But if you really want to use regex, a possible approach would be:

```py
string = re.sub('\\r*\\n*\\\\*', '', string)
```

When matching special characters, they need to be escaped with a backslash. When matching a backslash, though, you need to use four backslashes.

Comment: Doesn't that regex only substitute '\r\n'? I assumed OP wanted singular '\r' and '\n's removed too.

Comment: @jmu303 You are right, thanks. I edited the regex so it will match any number of '\r's and '\n's.

Comment: Similarly, I think `string.replace` would have to change as well, probably to two replace functions (one for `'\r'`, the other for `'\n'`)

Comment: @jmu303 Good point, you commented at the same time I was editing. In fact, three replace functions are needed because the OP wants to match backslashes as well.

Answer (score 4):

use `strict=False` when loading, see [python json docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
>>> s
'\n{\n\r\n\r\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\r\n"wordhere": 0}\n'
>>> json.loads(s, strict=False)
{u'wordhere': 0}
```